# css can't load images in other directory

Tags: css, apache

Strange thing. I moved my site from develop to production and now none of the images I load in my CSS file are working.

Directory structure:

```
root
root - css
root - icons
```

Example code from CSS:

```
.icon_edit {
    display: block;
    background:url(../icons/sharp_reply.png) center right no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

The code above does work on my staging server.
It also works if I move the images to the CSS folder and I change:

```
background:url(../icons/sharp_reply.png)
```

to

```
background:url(sharp_reply.png)
```

So it probably has something to do with the webserver (apache) config or some permission settings?
I just can't figure out which.

Comment: did you check all of the cases of files and folders?

Comment: Can you show html file that references to root-css and root-images

Comment: I doubt that has anything to do with Apache and is most likely due to your paths.

Comment: When I have that structure I generally use absolute paths (`/images/icons/sharp_reply.png`). There shouldn't be any problems with that...

Comment: Your example has 'images' as the sub folder while in the css file you refer to 'icons'... could that be it?

Comment: Did you check your folder permissions?  You need to have at least read access (700).

Comment: The strange thing is that it works on my staging server. I just copied from staging to production and now it isn't working anymore..? I've tried: url(/icons/sharp_reply.png), url(icons/sharp_reply.png), but I even set the whole path (/var/www/vhosts/ etc). None of this is working...? Also, and perhaps this helps, I can't access the .png files directly through the browser? I've checked the filepermissons: css/ => 755, icons/ => 755 and the root/ => 750.

Comment: Please check .htaccess file in your root folder, edit and delete all line code inside.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your directory from 'images' to 'icons'

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the message. The directory is called icons and the example I made is correct.